# Application crashes on Windows Vista

Tags: .net, mfc, crash, sql-server-ce, windows-vista

I have developed an application using .NET framework 4. It uses SQL CE and WPF.
The application already installed on many machines(Windows XP SP3/Windows 7/Windows 8) and it works fine. When some customers try to install it on machines running Windows Vista (with SP1 or SP2) the application crashes 
and it pops " *application* has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem.. ". I get no other exception messages and everything seems to be installed fine.
Can you suggest a solution?

Thanks

Comment: x64/x86 issue? Do you install the SQL CE MSI? Have you implemented proper unhandled execption handling? Have you done tracing with Process Monitor?

Comment: x86 issue. I have deployed sql ce by including the proper dll in my installation. I also have implemented exception handling. It s really difficult to do some tracing with Process Monitor because i cannot recreate the crashing in my machines. I 'll try to access the computer from team viewer and search in event handler and   run process monitor to see if i can find something to help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It turns out that i was not a x86 issue and it doesnot encounter only on windows vista. The same problem/error was observed on windows xp but there there was an error signature showing up. In Windows vista i had to inspect the error from the event handler.
The error showing was something similar to this:

Event Type: clr20r3  P1 :HelloWorld.exe   P2 : 1.0.0.0
                                 P3: 515b6326  P4: system.data.sqlserverce  P5 : 4.0.0.0
                                 P6: 4fcd17f1  P7: 8f0  P8: 25
                                 P9: System.windows.markup.xamlparse

After searching i found that the solution was to install this Microsoft update on the machines
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368